# How to specify the custom URL when i enter npm start in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

I wanted to load custom URL when i load the react using npm start in create-react-app. By default it will open localhost:somePort/.
But i need locahost:somePort/somestuff

Answer (score 4):

How about just redirect from you app.js to the path you want?
Like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
     <Route
        path='/'
        component={SomeComponent}
     />
     <Redirect to='/somestuff'/>
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```